# tcpip 3-way handshake

Tags: networking, tcp

Why is data not transferred during the 3rd part of TCP 3-way handshake?
e.g.

(A to B)SYN

(B to A)ACK+SYN

(A to B) ACK.... why cant data be transferred along with this ACK?

Comment: I don't see why it couldn't... The protocol specifies that the connection is established *after* B receives the ACK, though.

Answer (score 6):

I've always believed it was to keep the session establishment phase separate from the data transfer phase so that *no* real data is transferred until both ends of the session have agreed on the sequence numbers and session options, especially since packets arriving may be from a totally different, previous, session that just happens to have the same endpoints.

However, on further investigation, I'm not entirely certain that transmitting data with the handshake packets is disallowed. The section on TCP connection establishment in my *Internetworking with TCP/IP*<sup>1</sup> book contains the following snippet:

> Because of the protocol design, it is possible to send data along with the initial sequence numbers in the handshake segments. In such cases, the TCP software must hold the data until the handshake completes. Once a connection has been established, the TCP software can release data being held and deliver it to a waiting application program quickly.

Since it's certainly possible to construct a TCP packet with `SYN` (or `ACK`) *and* data, this may well be allowed. I've *never* seen it happen in the wild but, then again, I've never seen a hairy-eared dwarf lemur in the wild either, though I'm assured they exist.

It may be that it's the sockets software that prevents data going out before the session is fully established but TCP appears to consider it valid. It appears you can send data with a `SYN-ACK` packet (phase 2 of the connection establishment) since you have the other end's sequence number and options. Likewise, sending data with the phase 3 `ACK` packet appears to be possible as well.

The reason the TCP software holds on to the data until the handshake is fully complete is probably due to the reason mentioned above - only once both ends have agreed on the sequence numbers can you be sure that the data is not from a previous session.

---

<sup>1</sup> `Internetworking with TCP/IP Volume 1 Principles, Protocols and Architecture, 3rd edition, Douglas E. Comer, ISBN 0-13-216987-8.`

Comment: Makes you wonder if such data would sneak past any deep-packet-inspection filters out there that aren't expecting data in the initial handshake!