# TCP 3-way handshake - multiple SYNs

Tags: networking, tcp

Suppose host H1 is looking to make a TCP connection with H2 and sending a SYN for the 1st step of 3-way handshake. H1 then isn't hearing back in timeout and is sending a second SYN to H2.

Then, H1 is hearing back on both of these SYNs. What does H1 do in this case-- which one of these two does it ACK as the 3rd step of handshake, the first SYN+ACK from H2 or the second? The two SYN+ACK have 2 different Initial Sequence Numbers (ISNs) of H2. They also have different ACKs-- H1 sent 2 different ISNs in its two SYNs.

From another point - in such a case, what does H2 do? So - H2 received an SYN and sent SYN+ACK in response to it. After a while, H2 received another SYN+ACK from H1. What does H2 do in this case:

- send SYN+ACK to the second SYN as well? in this case, how does H2 know which SYN (the ISN of H1) is the one for this connection?

or

- ignore the second SYN. But then, H2 timed out as well-- it didn't hear back any since it send the previous SYN+ACK.

How is this handled in TCP?

TIA

Note: I've seen [What if a TCP handshake segment is lost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259774/what-if-a-tcp-handshake-segment-is-lost), [TCP: SYN request receives SYN response instead of SYN-ACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647956/tcp-syn-request-receives-syn-response-instead-of-syn-ack), [tcpip 3-way handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437569/tcpip-3-way-handshake) and [TCP handshake reliability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934516/tcp-handshake-reliability) along with some other useful discussions.

//------------------------------------------------

**EDIT:**

The answer seems to lie in the `RST` flag-- resetting whenever in doubt of the sequence#s. See Figure 9 of [RFC793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793).

However, the Q still stands in the light of the comment below: when does H1 ("TCP A" in Figure 9)
retry the connection with a new ISN of its-- how long after and under which circumstances?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related

Comment: The sequence number for a resubmitted SYN is the same as in the original SYN. What made you think this is not the case?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - the ISN is read from a counter ticking every "4 milliseconds" if I remember correctly. I assumed going by that clock in the second attempt. have you a reference handy to this?

Comment: @Roam: missing packets (which includes SYN) are retransmitted which means that exactly the same packet is sent again. The relevant standard is RFC 793.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - how then is the situation in Figure 9 of RFC793 coming up? See my edit in the Q-- portion below the line comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation in figure 9 happens when the SYN from a previous connection attempt arrives after the sender has already given up on that connection. Host B sends an ACK for this extra SYN, and Host A sees that the sequence number of the ACK is wrong. Then Host A aborts the connection by sending an RST.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is meaningless. Both SYNs are the same, from the point of view of sequence number, and both get acknowledged in the same way.